Getting response.status and response.url from the site visited
I am trying to get the page.url, response.url and response.status from the websites. This is what I am trying:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def scrape_page(url):
  
  with sync_playwright() as p:
      browser = p.chromium.launch()
      page = browser.new_page()
      page.goto(url)
      outs = {"url": page.url, "res_url": response.url, "res_status": response.status}
      browser.close()
      
  return outs

Individually, "url": page.url works. But if I add  "res_url": response.url, "res_status": response.status, it is giving me the following error:
>>> scrape_page("https://theguardian.co.uk")Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in scrape_page
NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Any idea how to fix the mistake?

Because response is not defined.

Did you try response = page.goto(url)?

When something isn't defined, define it:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright  # 1.44.0


def scrape_page(url):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        response = page.goto(url)
        # ^^^^^^^^^

        outs = {"url": page.url, "res_url": response.url, "res_status": response.status}
        browser.close()
        return outs


print(scrape_page("https://www.example.com"))

